# What are the difference between ASP.net instancing modes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The original question became redundant because it was based on a wrong assumption so it was edited to provide some info about [Sessions, Instancing and Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx) together with the accepted answer below.

Comment: Please elaborate.  E.g., are you talking about an Dependency Injection and an IoC container? which one... etc.

Comment: That linked article does neither contain the word `static` nor `AppDomain`. Where do you get that information from?

Comment: The link to the article is there to show `PerCall` description. The fact that statics are isolated comes from experience. `lock` on static reference works in `Single` mode, but does not work in `PerCall`mode. The assumption that `AppDomain`s are not created rises from observing CLR performance counters.

Comment: `static` variables can noot be isolated - there are just variables of diffirent application instances.

Comment: Statics cannot be isolated without using multiple app domains. And WCF of course will not create new app domain for each call. If you think otherwise - please provide concrete code on which you observe this behavior.

Comment: @Evk yeap, and that is what I believed, I panicked a little because our tests were exposing different behavior. Everything is solved though. It seems that our testers forgot that they had some machines running the same instances of the middle layer which led to multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Good to know! Then maybe update question somehow to let people know that it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will generally be the same across the various hosting types: IIS, Windows service, WCF.

> how does ASP.net implementation work inside, what mechanism is used to isolate static variables without creating a new AppDomain for every service call.

There is a good Code Project article that explains the differences at a high level, if you want to see under the hood you should use a Decompiler like ILSpy or Reflector to see the implementation details. **The difference in the implementation will be the way objects are singleton, instantiated or pooled per request or per session**.

Here is a snippet of the Code Project Article: [Three ways to do WCF instance management](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per)

[image]

[image]

[image]

To set the PerCall InstanceContext you use the ServiceBehaviour Attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

Here is the source code of the Service Behaviour Attribute:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ServiceBehaviorAttribute.cs,b743193260862969,references

Specifically where the instanceModeContext Provider is established:

```
dispatch.InstanceContextProvider = InstanceContextProviderBase.GetProviderForMode(this.instanceMode, dispatch);

if ((this.instanceMode == InstanceContextMode.Single) &&
    (dispatch.SingletonInstanceContext == null))
{
    if (singleton == null)
    {
        if (this.wellKnownSingleton != null)
        {
            singleton = new InstanceContext(serviceHostBase, this.wellKnownSingleton, true, false);
        }
        else if (this.hiddenSingleton != null)
        {
            singleton = new InstanceContext(serviceHostBase, this.hiddenSingleton, false, false);
        }
        else
        {
            singleton = new InstanceContext(serviceHostBase, false);
        }

        singleton.AutoClose = false;
    }
    dispatch.SingletonInstanceContext = singleton;
}
```

So you can see the difference is a switch between a wellKnownSingleton, a hiddenSingleton or neither and this is the implementation in the way objects are singleton, instantiated or pooled.

You can dig around the code base and look into the `channelDispatcher` code to see more info around implementation specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the nice post. As I said in comments above, we had a few instances running on different machines and it made me panic on a Friday evening 'cause my world where statics can only be isolated by creating `AppDomain` was broken ^-^